# Array of enum as string with null

Tags: java

Enum file looks like below.

```
package Tic;

public enum Player {
    X,O;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        switch (this) {
            case X: return "X";
            case O: return "O";
            default: return "_";
        }
    }
}
```

I have an array of array of enum to print as follows:
Returns a String representation of the board.
For example: "O _ X\nO X _\n _ _ _\n" (null  becomes _)
Is there a simple way to do so?

Comment: `null` won't become `_` because you use `this` in `switch` statement, so another value to represent an empty cell on the board is needed. It should be ok to add enum value `_` :)

Comment: @AlexRudenko Using `_` for an identifier is discouraged, and no longer possible since Java 9

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks, was not aware that `_` is a keyword :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using an enum value in place of null as this avoids possible NullPointerException when getting the string name equivalent. You can pass in the display name to a constructor as for @Charlie Armstrong example or this simple toString() override ensures the BLANK value prints correct display value for `player.toString()`:

```
public enum Player {
    X, O, BLANK;

    public String toString() {
        return this == BLANK ? "_" : this.name();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Player[] row = { Player.O, Player.BLANK, Player.X};
    for (Player p : row) {
        System.out.print(p.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so first let's rewrite your enum a little bit here.  You're using an instance method to convert from the enum to a string, but that doesn't actually make a lot of sense in your case, because you can't call methods on a null reference.  What you want is a static method, which determines if the argument is null or not and returns the appropriate string.  See below:

```java
public enum Player {
    // Declaring the strings here, which seems clearer than a switch statement:
    X("X"),
    O("O");

    private final String str;

    private Player(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return str;
    }

    // This is a static method, so you can pass null references here
    public static String toString(Player player) {
        if (player == null) {
            return "_";
        }

        // Here we can call the instance method, because we know player is not null
        return player.toString();
    }
}
```

With that out of the way, we can write some fairly simple driver code to achieve what you described:

```java
// This just sets up the array exactly like you described in the question:
Player[][] players = new Player[][] {
    {
        Player.O, null, Player.X
    },
    {
        Player.O, Player.X, null
    },
    {
        null, null, null
    }
};

// Loop through the outer array:
for (Player[] arr : players) {
    // For each outer array, we loop through the inner array:
    for (Player p : arr) {
        // For each Player in the inner array, we call our static toString() method and print the result:
        System.out.print(Player.toString(p));
    }

    //At the end of each inner array, we want to print a line terminator to separate them:
    System.out.println();
}
```

The output will be:

```
O_X
OX_
___
```

Comment: Remove the `str` field and the `toString()` method. Use the built in `.name()` method of enums and the default `toString()` impl, which is unsurprisingly the same as `name()`, which is in turn the enum instance name as a String.

Comment: @Bohemian Sure, that's another way to do it, but I think the `toString()` method more closely approximates the OP's code.  The `name()` method will always return the exact name of the enum constant, but what if the OP comes back later and decides that instead of using X and O, they want to use A and B?  They shouldn't have to rename the constants, which would require them to change everywhere they are referenced, instead they should just be able to change the `str` argument.  And what if they want two enum constants that both produce an O for some reason?

Comment: 2 constants with the same str? Not going to happen. *If* OP wanted to output something else than `name()`, *and* couldn't change the name of the enum accordingly, *then* you would complicate to code. Until then (ie forever), go with the simplest approach. Read [YAGNI](https://wiki.c2.com/?YouArentGonnaNeedIt). I live by it.

Comment: @Bohemian Fair comment, and the linked page was a good read.  I'm not saying using `name()` is wrong, it's certainly shorter and probably clearer, I'm just saying I think my answer is the closest to the OP's code, as it doesn't have any more compromises.  I see you've added your own answer, so both options are available to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static method that returns the built-in `.name()` method to get the String version of the enum instance, or underscore if null:

```
public enum Player {
    X, O;
    public static String asString(Player player) {
        return player == null ? "_" : player.name();
    }
}
```

To turn an array of Player into a string:

```
Player[] row = ...;
String rowAsString = Arrays.stream(row).map(Player::asString).collect(joining(""));
```